# Adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{b}_2$ is undecomposable

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{b}_2(\Bbb C)$.

Prove that adjoint representation $ad_\mathfrak{g}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ is undecomposable into a direct sum of irreducible representations.

My attempt:

I guess undecomposable means irreducible?
In that case:

I proved that commutator ideal $D(\mathfrak{g}) \neq \mathfrak{g}$ which means that $\mathfrak{g}$ is not simple.

On the other hand:

If we prove the aim of my original question, that would mean that $ad_\mathfrak{g}$ has subrepresentations and by the correspondance that $\mathfrak{g}$ is not simple.

I can't find my mistake, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "undecomposable" means that it cannot be written as a direct sum of irreducible representations. By Lie's Theorem, every irreducible representation of a complex solvable Lie algebra is $1$-dimensional. Hence the adjoint representation is reducible, but obviously not a direct sum of trivial representations.

Comment: Thank you! I can see that $\mathfrak{b}_2(\Bbb C)$ is nilpotent hence solvable. But is $\mathfrak{b}_2(\Bbb C)$ simple?

Comment: What is $\mathfrak b_2(\Bbb C)$ for you? I thought that you mean the $2$-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra, which is solvable but not nilpotent (and also not simple).

Comment: Oh sorry for confusion, for me $\mathfrak{b}_2(\Bbb C)$ if the subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(\Bbb C)$ of upper triangular matrices of size $2\times2$. I thought it was standard notation (like a Borel algebra)

Comment: Yes, this is the algebra I meant. This algebra is not nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that the adjoint representation is reducible because its dimension is $>1$. But I am not clear yet on why it can't be direct sum of trivial representations? Could you please explain more? I am sure it is obvious but I can't see it

Comment: Then the action would be trivial. But the action of the adjoint representation is not trivial.

Comment: Many thanks! that's clear to me now.